# What's a tidy way to transition a THHN ground wire out of EMT?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding

For some networking equipment (PoE security cameras, PoE IoT devices, outside point-to-point wireless links to other locations) that will be mounted on the perimeter and roof of my residence, I'm installing some lightning arrestors that need earth ground. My intention is to utilize the power system's ground for this need, and I'm looking for advice for how to make that tie in.

Generally, the locations I'm working in have junction boxes (mostly metal with EMT, though there are a few PVC boxes with NM). I'm trying to find neat solutions to tie in to the grounds in these two solutions so that I can ground the ethernet wiring arrestors. Assume these are all dry areas, and that the grounding wire I'm adding would be 12 AWG THHN. On the other end of the wire would be a grounding bridge that then the individual devices attached to.

Here's what I had in mind:

Where the nearby mains electrical is NM cable going into a PVC J-box, cut an additional hole into the J-box and install a cable gland sized appropriately and transition the wire out of the box that way. Secure the wire on the outside of the box reasonably close using a staple similar to how you would NM cable.

Where the nearby mains electrical is wire inside EMT and boxes, confirm that a nearby box is grounded properly and has a tight connection to the conduit, and use a ground wire pipe clamp. Attach my ground wire to that device.

So my questions are:

1. Is what I'm proposing compliant with 2020 NEC?
2. Are there better ways for me to achieve this?

Comment: When you say “networking equipment … outside”, do you mean that you're running something like an antenna and transceiver outside, mounted on your building? Or do you actually mean you're running network cable to another building (or a pole)? Those have quite different considerations and solutions. Consider [edit]ing your question to give some more detail on the physical arrangement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @KevinReid I added clarifications in the first paragraph for what the lightning arrestors will be protecting.

Comment: @Ryan -- do you have an intersystem bonding termination in your electrical system?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes, there's an IBT. Currently it just has the teleco's demarc tied to it.

Comment: @Ryan -- is tying your grounds into that IBT practical?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Here's what I'd do for that alternative:

- Add a sub system ground bus bar in the network cabinet that's tied in to the IBT
- Pull ground wires along side network drops where the arrestors are needed

While this would mean needing to pull a fair bit more of cabling, it would avoid the original question.

Comment: Wait, you want to intentionally attract lightning into entering your EGC part of your houses' electrical system?  Does the EMT have thick enough metal to carry a lightning strike? Does the Trans-Alaska Pipeline even?

Comment: Fun questions. The device I'm referring to is marketed as an ESD handling device. In general, with data networking outside, small amounts of static buildup or distant lightning strikes can impact the equipment. I'm trying to consider those use cases, not a direct strike. So while it is a "lightning arrestor", I have no qualms about the fact that it does not serve against carrying a direct lightning strike. I would expect in that scenario the entire house's wiring would be in a rough state regardless of how I have my IOT and security devices.